# Create a generic template for similar nodes in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

If I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <body1>
    <text1>this is a text</text1>
    <number1>1234,7</number1>
  </body1>
  <body2>
    <text2>this is a text</text2>
    <number2>1234,7</number2>
  </body2>
  <..>
</root>
```

How can I create a generic template for each `<body>`/`<text>` or `<number>` tags making it a generic one

Comment: Do you really have element names `body1`, `body2`, `text1`, `text2`?

Comment: yes, not the actual node names in the sample, but same concept, the number in body/text/number nodes can be any 2 character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a generic template for each `<body>/<text>` or
>   `<number>` tags making it a generic one

**There are many ways and which are applicable depends** on (all possible instances of) the XML document to be processed, of which you have shown us just one:

```
<xsl:template 
 match="*[starts-with(name(), 'body') and not(string-length(name() > 6))]
            /*[starts-with(name(), 'text') and not(string-length(name() > 6))]">
```

**and**

```
<xsl:template 
 match="*[starts-with(name(), 'body') and not(string-length(name() > 6))]
            /*[starts-with(name(), 'number') and not(string-length(name() > 8))]">
```

---

**Or, if you have just the shown XML document, you could use even**:

```
<xsl:template 
 match="*[starts-with(name(), 'text') and not(string-length(name() > 6))]">
```

**and**

```
<xsl:template 
 match="*[starts-with(name(), 'number') and not(string-length(name() > 8))]">
```

---

**Or even**:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what "generic" means in this context - perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'body')]">
```